# Regulate high negative voltage (below -30V)

Tags: ldo, negative

So I have seen Bost/Inverting switching regulators capable of producing high (positive or negative) output voltages due to the many possibilities associated with switched regulators.

However, to obtain low noise supply rails, I need to follow the switching regulator by LDOs and filters. For positive voltages, there are LDOs that can continuously operate on input voltages as high as +60 or even +75 V and outputs in the same order of magnitude.

What about negative voltages?

1. Why are there no LDOs operating below -37V (must have to do with the internat design?)
2. How would I produce a *clean* -55V signal from +5V? (without just using an inverting switching regulator on its own)

NOTE: I am happy with about 50mA of output current ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as using a 3-terminal negative adjustable regulator (not sure there are **any** very low noise ones if you're interested in uV noise), you could isolate the output voltage with a galvanically isolated DC-DC converter and then use a positive low-noise regulator and post-filter to get down to very low noise levels.

Answer (score 1):

They do exist, you just need to use an inverting controller with external switch, e.g. LT3757. Then you can up the voltage rating of the external switch to whatever output voltage you would like, plus some margin of course. Practical tip: make sure you read the datasheets well. If you're inverting a fairly small positive voltage into a large negative voltage, you will need very high duty cycles. Not all dc/dc controllers will support this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however - i am totally aware of the fact that there are SWITCHING controllers/regulators that allow such a high negative voltage, but as I tried to explain, i need to "clean up" / regulate the supply somehow after the switching regulator, so I asked about LDOs (or something that acts like a LDO ;-) ) that operates on such voltages so that i can use is as follower after the switching regulator

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I apparently didn't properly read your question. Or I was still a bit sleepy. The same applies here: use a discrete pass element LDO for your application. This can be as simple as using a fairly linear MOSFET + LM358.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - so for my understanding: even with a discrete pass-element, i need a regulator that supports the controlling of such a pass-element (and this also involves some "high-voltage" drive capability of the regulator IC itself? )

Comment: No, you don't necessarily. Two ways: either use a BJT as a pass device, which turns it into current control which you can do with relatively low voltage devices, or reference the entire circuit to the negative voltage, so the absolute voltages seen by the opamp and gate/base of the pass element are small.

Comment: I am not sure that's as easy as you are implying. Is power dissipation an issue? What about an old zener diode? That can work quite well, not as well as an LDO of course but it might work well enough.

Comment: Zeners are not that quiet. Also, if your load is changing you really want an active LDO supply, not something passive. This is also important for PSRR in general. If you're looking for a completely passive solution, you can always use a well-tuned LC filter.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they exist. [Here's](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/hirel/om7612st.pdf) one - all it requires is that the input-output voltage differential is no more than 50V.

[image]

The output voltage is set by the current taken through R1 and R2 up to ground - none of the pins have to see a very high voltage with respect to each other and "as an island" this means the device doesn't know that it is 10 volts below ground or a 100 volts below ground.

This device isn't an LDO type but the same principle exists - treat the device as an island and if necessary protect from differential overload using a zener diode or a couple of series diodes.

Comment: Thanks Andy! =) One thing I am curious right now, however: Should´nt this approach work well with other negative voltage LDOs as well?

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I forgot that most LDOs have a GND pin besides of the ADJ input, that makes "preserving the island" difficult ;-) Thanks!